# What DAL technology to use for a .NET/Angular project?

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, data-access-layer

I am in the process of setting up a new web app and will be using Angular and .NET WebAPI. I am looking for a robust framework that I can use for the Data Access Layer. Something that I can quickly get up and running but also helps me easily update table objects, setup lookup data and perform post upgrade operations.

In my previous project, I used EF Code first and although it 'works', I found that Migrations are messy and having a clean ability to maintain scripts for upgrade/setup doesn't exist (or I am not aware of).

Which DAL technology can I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with Entity Framework (migrations aside) and you need to get something up quickly and easily I would recommend to stick with it.  You can use the EF "Code First" approach where you create your models and mappings in code without using migrations.  You could manage your scripts in a different way such as using a Visual Studio database project or DBUp.

That said the real answer is "It Depends" based on the specific needs of your new project and what you need from your data access layer.  There are other SQL-based alternatives such Dapper and even ADO.NET but also other solutions such as RavenDB.

Comment: Thanks. So, how does the EF Code first + DBUp really look like? Do I write SQL scripts for changes to tables/views/seed data and use DBUp to execute it? What's the responsibility of EF Code first at that point?

Comment: Yes that's basically what it would be like if you were to use DBUp.  You write scripts for incremental changes to your database.  "Code First" isn't a good name as it gives the impression that it is responsible for database generation which isn't necessarily the case.  Code First has always worked with existing databases and gives you a code-centric view of your database and mapping configurations rather than a database-centric view.